# Scrolling lag using mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll

there.

I'm noticing that my WordPress site have a laggy scrolling using a mobile device.

Example of one of my posts: http://www.hipertrofia.org/blog/2018/03/30/dor-na-lombar-agachamento/

Can this be caused by a bad CSS coding?

I don't know anything about CSS coding, can you give me a light where to start?

I searched for this and people tell that you cant use "fixed" for mobiles, but I can't find any object using fixed in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    html, body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content is too heavy. It even lags in my laptop browser(Chrome). Use Inspect Element and do a performance test to identify the problem. Try reducing the quality of images and try to use less scripts.

[image]

[image]